# How to set up a subdomain for a website using Netlify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, netlify

Hello StackOverflow experts

If want to have a website showcasing my work under the subdomain **/work**, must I have the files in the root website folder **/work**  or can I just add a new folder named work and upload my code for the subdomain **/work** there? I am using Netlify for hosting and Hover for my domains.

Thank you very much for your help. If you have any questions, please just write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add folder **work** in the root directory and upload there code.